# How do you use regex to split a string

Tags: c#

how do i use regex to split a string such as `Manga vol 1-515` into 2 different outputs i want `Manga vol 1-5` as 1 output and `15` as another. i want to output them both into 2 separate text boxes the last 2 digits of the string will always be what i want to split. currently my solution is

```
string pricepat = "[1,3,4][5,9,0]";
string Price = BtnGlobal.Text.ToString();
string priceMatches = Regex.Split(Price, pricepat);                
Pricetxt.Text = priceMatches.ToString();
```

Comment: Please find a regex tutorial which will tell you this information.

Comment: There seems to be a complete disconnect between `"[1,3,4][5,9,0]"` and `"Manga vol 1-515"` to me.

Comment: Could ypu, please, describe the *pattern* in a plain English? Do you want just take `2` last characters (`"15"`) from the initial string (`"Manga vol 1-515"`)? If so, `string part1 = source.Substring(0, source.Length - 2); string part2 = source.Substring(source.Length - 2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Regex Match** to get the last two characters

```
string input = "Manga vol 1-515";
var result = Regex.Match(input, @"(.{2})\s*$");

txtFirst.Text = input.Replace(result.ToString(), "");
txtSecond.Text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: but how would i output both results into texboxes, so the last 2 digits into one textbox and the rest into another textbox

Comment: Refer my edited answer. You could also consider using `string.Substring` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can split it without Regex caption groups,
and check that your string have at least two chars

```
string input = "Manga vol 1-515";
string firstPart = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 2);
string lastTwo = input.Substring(input.Length - 2);
```